# How do I see who I am following on steam?

Tags: steam

How can I see who I am following on steam? Like an author or something? I have looked all around the internet and cannot find the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check who you are following, navigate to `Friends` tab and select `Following` group.

[Click here](http://steamcommunity.com/my/friends/following) (if you're already logged in to Steam) or go to `http://steamcommunity.com/id/<YOUR_ID>/friends/following/`.

Answer (score 2):

In Steam, from the top menu, click on `Friends` under your `Profile Name` and then click on `Following` on the `Friends Page`

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: You're late... You might as well should've just added that picture as an edit.